# How to make Nginx config file for Django Project?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I made Nginx config for My Django project.

For DNS I associate with my IP.

But this config not working, when I'm checking xyz.com in web but getting error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/project/project.sock;
    }
}
```

Please correct me if i'm doing wrong.

Comment: 1.  What is giving you connection refused, nginx or django?  2.  How are you running django?  3.  Are you sure the socket is at the /home/ubuntu/project/project.sock and that the `nginx` user has access to it?

Comment: Are you sure the socket is at the /home/ubuntu/project/project.sock and that the nginx user has access to it?   Yes, It wos working but when i change on it its not working

Comment: What is giving you connection refused, nginx or django? ===> nothing No Nginx error or no django error its look like ip not associate

Comment: How are you running django? == Running through gunicorn